# Does MXNet read training data from S3 in a streaming fashion?

Tags: mxnet

[This](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/s3_integration.html) page talks about reading training data from S3 bucket directly. Does anybody know if the data is read in a streaming fashion or if the entire training data is copied to a local cache before training begins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is actually read in a streaming fashion. If you want to cache the entire file locally, you need to do that manually or by using a script before the training begins.

Note that some iterators might read the entire .rec file (to get some metadata) before training begins if .lst file is not provided. It is a good idea to provide both the .rec and .lst files while creating the iterator.

Example:

```
itr = mxnet.image.ImageDetIter(batch_size=32, data_shape=(3,300,300),
                               path_imgrec=“s3://my_bucket_name/training_data/train.rec”,
                               path_imglist=“s3://my_bucket_name/training_data/train.lst”)
```